# PHP find phonetic in random password script

Tags: php

I have written this random password script which works perfectly.

Although I would like to add additional line below showing the phanetic alphabet for the random password.

How would be the best way to implement this?

```
 <?php
function random_readable_pwd($length=10){

    // the wordlist from which the password gets generated 
    // (change them as you like)
    $words = 'AbbyMallard,AbigailGabble,AbisMal,Abu,Adella,TheAgent,AgentWendyPleakley,Akela,AltheAlligator';

    $phonetic = array("a"=>"alfa","b"=>"bravo","c"=>"charlie","d"=>"delta","e"=>"echo","f"=>"foxtrot","g"=>"golf","h"=>"hotel","i"=>"india","j"=>"juliett","k"=>"kilo","l"=>"lima","m"=>"mike","n"=>"november","o"=>"oscar","p"=>"papa","q"=>"quebec","r"=>"romeo","s"=>"sierra","t"=>"tango","u"=>"uniform","v"=>"victor","w"=>"whisky","x"=>"x-ray","y"=>"yankee","z"=>"zulu");

   // Split by ",":
    $words = explode(',', $words);
    if (count($words) == 0){ die('Wordlist is empty!'); }

    // Add words while password is smaller than the given length
    $pwd = '';
    while (strlen($pwd) < $length){
        $r = mt_rand(0, count($words)-1);
        $pwd .= $words[$r];
    }

    $num = mt_rand(1, 99);
     if ($length > 2){
        $pwd = substr($pwd,0,$length-strlen($num)).$num;
    } else { 
        $pwd = substr($pwd, 0, $length);
    }

   $pass_length = strlen($pwd);
   $random_position = rand(0,$pass_length);

   $syms = "!@#%^*()-?";
   $int = rand(0,9);
   $rand_char = $syms[$int];

   $pwd = substr_replace($pwd, $rand_char, $random_position, 0);

    return $pwd;
}
?>
<html><head><title>Password generator</title></head>
<body><p><?php echo random_readable_pwd(10); ?></p></body>
</html>
```

E.g outputs:

**Alt!heAll87**

ALFA lima tango ! hotel echo ALFA lima lima 8 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just loop through the generated password character by character and build up a phonetic string that way.

For example (customize to your code and needs, bottom example hasn't been tested but should give you an understanding of how you could approach it):

```
$password = "aBcDefG";
$phonetics = array("a"=>"alfa","b"=>"bravo","c"=>"charlie","d"=>"delta","e"=>"echo","f"=>"foxtrot","g"=>"golf","h"=>"hotel","i"=>"india","j"=>"juliett","k"=>"kilo","l"=>"lima","m"=>"mike","n"=>"november","o"=>"oscar","p"=>"papa","q"=>"quebec","r"=>"romeo","s"=>"sierra","t"=>"tango","u"=>"uniform","v"=>"victor","w"=>"whisky","x"=>"x-ray","y"=>"yankee","z"=>"zulu");
$phonetic = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($password); $i++) {
    $char = substr($password, $i, 1);
    $phonetic[] = (ctype_upper($char) ? strtoupper(strtr(strtolower($char), $phonetics)) : strtolower(strtr($char, $phonetics)));
}
$phonetic = join(' ', $phonetic);
echo $phonetic;
```

**EDIT** My code was faulty, I updated it and tested it. The output is: alfa BRAVO charlie DELTA echo foxtrot GOLF

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I need to loop through each character using string length. The hard part I can't figure out is the replacing with the phonetic array and testing the case.

Comment: That worked brilliantly first time, thank you. I see the way you have used the $i in the substr to pinpoint each character.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes you just use the $i to iterate through the characters :)